# Button for a webview android

Tags: android, webview, android-tabhost

i was wondering is it possible to add a button below a webview such that on clicking it, it should flip and give another webpage and so on, maybe a back button to return to the previous webpage, Can we make such changes in the layout> if so how? Coz whenever I wrote TabHost program for webview, upon selecting the tab,it would fill the entire page hiding the tabs,

I want to create a combination of ViewFlipper, WebView and Button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a layout with a flipper.
In your code, try

`WebView myWebView1 = ...;

WebView myWebView2 = ...;

Flipper myFlipper = (Flipper)(findViewById(R.id_myflipper);

myFlipper.addView(myWevView1);

myFlipper.addView(myWebView2)`

when you press your button, change the current view in the flipper by

```
myFlipper.setDisplayedChild(flipperID);
```

Where flipperID is the index of the view you want to show.